# Javacsript/CSS not working correctly in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Really hoping someone can help me as I've been trying to fix this for weeks! I have some css slide/fade effects that are triggered when user clicks any of the text links on the yellow section of [this page](http://daisy.garywestjr.com/), all working fine in Chrome but on Safari the following is happening:

When you click the text link to go to the next page, then you go back to the home page the effects are triggered again when the home page loads, and then if you click another link the effects are not triggered. There must be a simple solution to get this working on Safari?

Sorry I cant post a working snippet here, but its an entire page that is effected and only on Safari so its difficult to replicate it here. I have added the CSS and JS that im using though.

```js
  jQuery(".hometext").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("slide");
    jQuery(".hometext").toggleClass("active");
        jQuery("#header-elementor").toggleClass("active");
  })
})
```

```css
.hometext.active {

  animation: fadeOutBottomLeft; /* referring directly to the animation's @keyframe declaration */
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.hometext.slide {

  animation: fadeOutTopRight; /* referring directly to the animation's @keyframe declaration */
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey try restarting your program and your pc too coz if its working fine on google chrome then it should also work for safari  too sometimes it happens when we work for too long

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is fine. Safari is showing some security issues. It says it can't set up a secure connection to the webserver. Maybe there is an issue with your certificate or other security settings on your server.

Comment: hey, i havent installed an SSL certificate just yet as the site is not live on the actual domain, but i cant figure out how to fix this issue.